# How to report custom Go error types to Sentry?

Tags: go, sentry

I want my custom error to show up in Sentry, but it just grabs the underlying `errorString` type.
Is there a way to show `operationTimeoutError` instead?

Here's what I do:

```golang
type operationTimeoutError error
var errOperationTimeout operationTimeoutError = errors.New("TIMEOUT")

func foo() {
    sentry.CaptureException(errOperationTimeout)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sentry will call the Error() method in the error you provided, which in return prints the error message of the underlying error. you can either override the Error method for the custom error type or map it to a new error with the message you intend to see in sentry. Since its likely that you are using the error for other purposes like logging, I think mapping is the better choice.

```
func mapError(err error)error{
   switch err.(type){
      case operationTimeoutError:
        return errors.New("operationTimeoutError")
      default:
        return err
   }
}

sentry.CaptureException(mapError(errOperationTimeout))
```